# Unity: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: unity-container

Is there a simple way of finding out what 'this object' is?

Comment: Usually Unity provides you some more detailed information in an inner exception of the ResolutionFailedException that hits your app.

Comment: So it does! I've also just discovered some unfortunate-ness in Unity. If a constructor throws an exception, Unity returns a 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object'. <= Not true!

Comment: Why don't you leave your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually Unity provides you some more detailed information in an inner exception of the ResolutionFailedException that hits your app.